# реконструкция функции из ее логического портрета (паттерна)

Tags: r

создадим некий вектор `х`

```
set.seed(1)
x <- cumsum(rnorm(10))
plot(x,t="b")
```

[image: х]

теперь создадим его логический паттерн. Что я имею ввиду, мы просто берем вектор `х` , выбираем из него две точки и сравниваем их между собой логическим условием (первая точка больше второй? ответ `TRUE/FALSE`) и так по две точки перебираем все возможные комбинации в `х`
для этого написал простую функцию `to.logyc`

```
to.logyc <- function(x){
cmb <- combn(length(x),2) # сзд. все комбинации индексов
logic.pattern <- rep(NA,ncol(cmb))

for(i in 1:ncol(cmb)){
  i1 <- cmb[1,i]
  i2 <- cmb[2,i]
  logic.pattern[i] <- x[i1] > x[i2]
}
return(logic.pattern)
}
```

запустим функцию `to.logyc` на векторе `Х`

```
 to.logyc(x)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[17] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[33] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

на выходе получили логический вектор (логический паттерн) вектора `Х`

А теперь собственно сам вопрос как восстановить/реконструировать ветор `Х` по этому логическому паттерну, чтобы получить что то типа этого

```
rezult.pattern <- c(1,2,5,4,3,9,8,7,6,10)
plot(rezult.pattern,t="b")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно сравнить, с логической точки зрение паттерны идентичны

```
orig.logyc <- to.logyc(x)
 reconst.logyc <- to.logyc(rezult.pattern)
 all( orig.logyc == reconst.logyc)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: для получения того, что вы хотите, надо сохранять не два состояния — «больше»/«не больше», а три — «меньше»/«равно»/«больше». а с тем, что у вас сейчас, можно получить максимум такой вектор: `0 0 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для получения того, что вы хотите, надо сохранять не два состояния — «больше»/«не больше», а три — «меньше»/«равно»/«больше». а с тем, что у вас сейчас, можно получить максимум такой вектор: `0 0 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 0`.

пример получения:

```
t <- to.logyc(x)
n <- function(x) (-1+sqrt(1+8*length(x)))/2+1
v <- rep(0, n(t))
e <- length(t)
for(i in (length(v)-1):1) {
  for(j in (length(v)):(i+1)) {
    if(t[e]) v[i]<-v[j]+1
    e <- e - 1
  }
}
v
 [1] 0 0 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 0
```

---

p.s. чтобы получить ту же псевдослучайную последовательность, что и у автора вопроса, мне пришлось сменить алгоритм, используемый генератором псч:

```
RNGkind(kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG", normal.kind = "Inversion")
```

по умолчанию у меня было так (версия `r` — 3.5.2):

```
RNGkind(kind = "default", normal.kind = "default")
RNGkind()
 [1] "Mersenne-Twister" "Inversion"
```

см. справку к функции `RNGkind()`:

```
?RNGkind
```